# Search everywhere

Tags: search

Right know for my search engine i am using:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages, references, trainingsList, maps, trendsAndInnovation, currentTopics).search(query).order('score') %}
```

So now if i would add another section i have to add it to the code as well of course.
Is there a way to directly search for everything on the page?

Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just remove the `section` parameter altogether.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}
```